# No output shown on problem 8 of project euler

Tags: c

This is [problem 8 of project euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8).

I don't understand why no output is shown. Please don't write direct solution, I just wan't to know where my logic is wrong.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //code

    char a[1001]='7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450';

    int p,i=0,m;
    for(p=1;i<13;i++)p=p*((int)a[i]-48);m=p;printf("%d %d\n",m,p);
    for(;i<1001&&a[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        p=p/((int)(a[i-13]-48));
        p=p*((int)(a[i]-48));
        if(m<p)m=p;
    }
    printf("%d\n",m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please reformat question to include description of the result you want, and the link to project Euler should be in body, so that it is clickable.

Comment: Using single quotes `''` for initialization of `a` makes no sense. You should get compiler warnings or errors for that. If not, then please check your compiler settings.

Comment: Note that to obtain the product of 13 single digits you'll need a variable with bigger range than a 32-bit `int`. For example 9^13 = 2541865828329.

Comment: A string literal must be enclosed in double quotes `"`, not single ones `'`.

Comment: Please, edit the source to make it a little more readable... :)

Comment: Some output is shown, so what are you asking at all?  (of course, after correcting the `'7316717653...'` -> `"7316717653..."` in the string)

Comment: The code with fail with a division by 0 in line 12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some errors in the posted code, both syntactic and logical.

As already noted, you should use double quotes for the string literal. You could also write it splitted in different lines, the compiler will concatenate all the chuncks and add the `\0` terminator.

```
const char *digits = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
                      // ...
                     "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
```

The type `int` may be too small to represent the value of the product. The Standard only guarantees it to be capable of representing numbers up to 32767 and even a 32-bit (common this days) `int` can't store 9<sup>13</sup>. I'd suggest using a `long long` and more meaningful names, e.g.:

```
#define MAX_ADJACENT_DIGITS 13
// ...
long long product = 0, max_product = 0;
int n_digits = 0;
```

The error in your algorithm is that it doesn't consider what happens when a digit is zero. An integer division by zero could lead to a runtime error, and besides that, all the products of the nearby digits are equal to zero.

Consider this modified version:

- For every character in the string, from the first up to the one which is equal to `'\0'`

  - If it's equal to `'0'` (note the single quotes and the use of the actual char, not a "magic" number)

    - reset `product` and `n_digits`.
    - Skip the rest of the loop body (`continue;`).
  - If it's the first digit of a group of adjacent digits (`n_digits == 0`)

    - than `product` is equal to that digit  and we can increase `n_digits`.
    - Continue with the next digit.
  - Here we can update the product (`product *= digits[i] - '0';`) and increase `n_digits`.
  - If we have exceeded the maximum number of adjacent digits

    - remove the oldest one (`product /= digits[i - MAX_ADJACENT_DIGITS] - '0';`) from the product and reset `n_digits` to the maximum.
    - Update the maximum value of the products, if the current product is bigger.

Following those steps, your program should find the sub-sequence of digits `"5576689664895"` and output their product.

Comment: I understand where i was wrong and I feel stupid for not noticing those zeroes. thanks for your answer it really helped

Comment: Better divide the string in substrings of 13 or more characters, separated by `0` digits... not?  as any `0` digit will produce a 0 result.  Shorter sequences must be discarded (as they produce a zero result) and longer or equal are the only ones to be considered (they don't have `0` digits at all)

Comment: @LuisColorado If you are suggesting to delay the evaluation of the products until a long enough substring of non zero digits is found, that sounds like a good idea. It doesn't seem to make much of an impact in this particular case, though: [1](http://quick-bench.com/8E_IPy9xItsPlR_lfaKOOH6qxNE) or [2](http://quick-bench.com/5Rts_FGcoH1njWowSbEmp0WZ_lI), but I'm sure you may provide a better implementation.

Comment: I wrote a solution to that and it works quite well... As the OP requested not to publish a working solution, I decided not to include it in a response.

Comment: It's curious to find sequences of less than 13 characters that end with products larger than the 13 characters approach.  I have not checked the verbose traces in my program, but they must be sequences surrounded by `0` chars.

Comment: @LuisColorado Nice. It doesn't appear so, with the given input string. Are you thinking about a particular algorithm (memoizing?) or a "brute force" approach (just change the max # of digits)?

Comment: @Bob__, I made a bug selecting a 32bit integer for the product.... i've changed that in my solution repository of github.  (also in my response to this question)

Answer (score 4):

You have wrong quotes in the initializer of `char a[1001]` - single quotes are for a *character constant*, use double quotes for a *string literal*. And get a better compilation environment - one which warns about such mistakes.

Then, the idea of removing the thirteenth-to-last factor from the current product seems clever at first sight, but it breaks if the digit is zero and you try to divide by it.

Comment: thanks for answering i really didn't notice 0s and I didn't knew about single and double quotation mark I thought any quotation can be used like in python.

Answer (score 3):

you have to change char `a[1001] = '123';` to `char a[] = "123";` then run it.here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //code
    //' ' is used for single character, " " is for string.
    char a[]="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

    int p, i=0, m;

    for(p=1;i<13;i++)
    {
        p = p * ( (int)a[i] - 48);
        m = p;
        printf("%d %d\n", m, p);
    }
    for( ; i < (1001 && a[i]!='\0'); i++)
    {
        p= p / ((int)(a[i-13] - 48));
        p= p * ((int)(a[i] - 48));
        if(m < p)
            m = p;
    }
    printf("%d\n",m);
    return 0;
}
```

```
output -:
7 7
21 21                                                                                                                          
126 126                                                                                                                        
882 882                                                                                                                        
882 882                                                                                                                        
6174 6174  
37044 37044                                                                                                                    
185220 185220                                                                                                                  
555660 555660                                                                                                                  
555660 555660 
5000940 5000940                                                                                                                
5000940
```

Comment: This fails with a '0' early in the string with a division by 0.

Answer (score 3):

This is my approach to the solution of euler #8.  It first uses the `strok(3)` function to separate the complete string into pieces separated by `0` chars.  Then it slides a window of length `n` over the separated strings (strings of length less than `n` cannot get enough digits to form a product without involving a `0` so they are discarded.

We then construct the first product by multiplying the first set of `n` digits.  Once it is set, the window is sliced, by multiplying the product by the next digit and dividing the product by the last digit in a queue, pointed by `p` and `q`.  Products are compared with the maximum and in case they are larger, the position of the match and the new value of the product are stored.

At the end, the substring is printed, starting at the stored position, the index is printed and the product.

The program accepts the options `-n` and `-v`:

- `-n` *number* allows to specify a different number (defaults to 13, as euler #8 indicates)
- `-v` produces more output, indicating at each step the string to be tested, and the products involved.

To compile the program, just:

```
cc -o 8 8.c
```

and to run it, just execute `8` at the command line.

**If you don't want to see at the solution, don't continue reading.**

---

## 8.c

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FLAG_VERBOSE    (1 << 0)

int flags = 0;

int n = 13;
char N[] = 
                "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
                "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
                "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
                "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
                "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
                "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
                "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
                "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
                "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
                "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
                "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
                "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
                "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
                "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
                "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
                "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
                "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
                "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
                "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
                "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:v")) != EOF) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'n':
            if (sscanf(optarg, "%d", &n) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "invalid number: %s\n",
                        optarg);
            }
            break;
        case 'v':
            flags |= FLAG_VERBOSE;
            break;
        } /* switch */
    } /* while */

    if (flags & FLAG_VERBOSE) {
        printf( "n = %d;\n"
                "N = \"%s\"\n",
                n, N);
    }

    char *p, *res = NULL;
    unsigned long long res_prod = 0;
    for (p = strtok(N, "0"); p; p = strtok(NULL, "0")) {
        if (strlen(p) < n) continue;
        char *q = p;
        unsigned long long prod = 1LL;
                int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { /* initial product */
            prod *= *p++ - '0';
        }
        for(;;) {
            int larger = prod > res_prod;
            if (flags & FLAG_VERBOSE)
                printf("Trying %.*s ==> %llu%s\n",
                        n, q, prod,
                        larger ? " !" : "");
            if (larger) {
                res = q; res_prod = prod;
            }
            if (!*p) break;
            prod /= *q++ - '0';
            prod *= *p++ - '0';
        }
    }
    if (res) {
        int pos = res - N;
        printf("Largest product at position %d (%s%.*s%s): %llu\n",
               pos,
               pos ? "..." : "", n, res,
               pos < sizeof N - 1 - n ? "..." : "",
               res_prod);
    } else {
        printf("No solution found\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a sliding window approach. First grow the window to size 13 and reset the window every time you hit a `'0'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(){
    const char a[] = 
                "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
                "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
                "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
                "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
                "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
                "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
                "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
                "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
                "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
                "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
                "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
                "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
                "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
                "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
                "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
                "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
                "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
                "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
                "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
                "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    uint64_t prod = 1;
    uint64_t m = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(a) - 1; ++i) {
        prod *= a[i] - '0';
        if (prod == 0) {
            prod = 1;
            count = 0;
        } else {
            if (count++ >= 13) {
                prod /= a[i - 13] - '0';
            }
            if ((count >= 13) && (prod > m)) m = prod;
        }
    }
    printf("max = %"PRIu64"\n", m);
}
```